# Count the minimum number of jumps required for a frog to get to the other side of a river

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance

I work with a Codility problem provided below,

The Fibonacci sequence is defined using the following recursive formula:

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(M) = F(M - 1) + F(M - 2) if M >= 2
```

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is initially located at one bank of the river (position −1) and wants to get to the other bank (position N). The frog can jump over any distance F(K), where F(K) is the K-th Fibonacci number. Luckily, there are many leaves on the river, and the frog can jump between the leaves, but only in the direction of the bank at position N.

The leaves on the river are represented in an array A consisting of N integers. Consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive positions from 0 to N − 1 on the river. Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s:

0 represents a position without a leaf;
1 represents a position containing a leaf.
The goal is to count the minimum number of jumps in which the frog can get to the other side of the river (from position −1 to position N). The frog can jump between positions −1 and N (the banks of the river) and every position containing a leaf.

For example, consider array A such that:

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 0
A[2] = 0
A[3] = 1
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 0
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 0
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 0
A[10] = 0
```

The frog can make three jumps of length F(5) = 5, F(3) = 2 and F(5) = 5.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array A consisting of N integers, returns the minimum number of jumps by which the frog can get to the other side of the river. If the frog cannot reach the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 0
A[2] = 0
A[3] = 1
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 0
A[6] = 1
A[7] = 0
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 0
A[10] = 0
```

the function should return 3, as explained above.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range `[0..100,000]`;
each element of array A is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is `O(N*log(N))`;
expected worst-case space complexity is `O(N)` (not counting the storage required for input arguments).

I wrote the following solution,

```
class Solution {
    private class Jump {
        int position;
        int number;

        public int getPosition() {
            return position;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public Jump(int pos, int number) {
            this.position = pos;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }

    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int N = A.length;

        List<Integer> fibs = getFibonacciNumbers(N + 1);

        Stack<Jump> jumps = new Stack<>();
        jumps.push(new Jump(-1, 0));

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[N];

        while (!jumps.isEmpty()) {

            Jump jump = jumps.pop();

            int position = jump.getPosition();
            int number = jump.getNumber();

            for (int fib : fibs) {

                if (position + fib > N) {
                    break;
                } else if (position + fib == N) {
                    return number + 1;
                } else if (!visited[position + fib] && A[position + fib] == 1) {

                    visited[position + fib] = true;
                    jumps.add(new Jump(position + fib, number + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }


    private List<Integer> getFibonacciNumbers(int N) {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        int i = 2;

        while (list.get(list.size() - 1) <= N) {

            list.add(i, (list.get(i - 1) + list.get(i - 2)));
            i++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            list.remove(i);
        }

        return list;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = new int[11];

    A[0] = 0;
    A[1] = 0;
    A[2] = 0;
    A[3] = 1;
    A[4] = 1;
    A[5] = 0;
    A[6] = 1;
    A[7] = 0;
    A[8] = 0;
    A[9] = 0;
    A[10] = 0;

    System.out.println(solution(A));
   }
}
```

However, while the correctness seems good, the performance is not high enough.  Is there a bug in the code and how do I improve the performance?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't need a list and just one for loop.. MAYBE

Comment: Flopshot: if you having nothing to contribute, consider to contribute nothing. There is no point in being snappy here. This is a well written question. I think it is off topic here, but for sure the OP put in quite some effort and should not be ridiculed.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos what do you mean?

Comment: @GhostCat I oppose as the question is about how to imrpove the performance. I dont need any help to improve the design etc

Comment: I don’t disagree that it’s a well written question. I’ve asked these kinds of questions before several times only to never have them answered. I agree that my snappiness is in I’ll taste, but the fact remains that these kinds of questions litter SO with useless trivia. Rather, SO was built to help developers with real problems, not trivia generated by interviewers to arbitrarily gauge candidates with questions irrelevant to Java development

Comment: @flopshot Sorry, but you are wrong. What is *trivia* to you might be somebody else's real problem. What litters SO are the countless **badly** written no-attempt-drop-me-codez questions. And when you are really concerned about those, invest some time to grow your reputation, so you can participate in voting on content, may it be down/close/... whatever votes. That is what contribution means, not being snappy on a well written question.

Comment: @GhostCat I completely agree with you.

Comment: You should use a QUEUE AND NOT A STACK. This is a form of breadth-first search and your code needs to visit nodes which are added first to the queue to get the minimum distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [knapsack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-problem/) algorithms to solve this problem.
In my solution I precomputed fibonacci numbers. And applied knapsack algorithm to solve it. It contains duplicate code, did not have much time to refactor it. Online ide with the same code is in [repl](https://repl.it/@omurbekjk/HarmoniousUntimelyGeeklog)

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {

public static int solution(int[] A) {

    int N = A.length;
    int inf=1000000;
    int[] fibs={1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025};
    int[] moves = new int[N+1];
     for(int i=0; i<=N; i++){
        moves[i]=inf;
     }
    for(int i=0; i<fibs.length; i++){
        if(fibs[i]-1<N && A[fibs[i]-1]==1){
            moves[ fibs[i]-1 ] = 1;
        }
        if(fibs[i]-1==N){
           moves[N] = 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        if(A[i]==1)
        for(int j=0; j<fibs.length; j++){
            if(i-fibs[j]>=0 && moves[i-fibs[j]]!=inf && moves[i]>moves[i-fibs[j]]+1){
                moves[i]=moves[i-fibs[j]]+1;
            }                
        }
         System.out.println(i + " => " + moves[i]);
    }

     for(int i=N; i<=N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<fibs.length; j++){
            if(i-fibs[j]>=0 && moves[i-fibs[j]]!=inf && moves[i]>moves[i-fibs[j]]+1){
                moves[i]=moves[i-fibs[j]]+1;
            }                
        }
         System.out.println(i + " => " + moves[i]);
    }

    if(moves[N]==inf) return -1;
    return moves[N];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] A = new int[4];

A[0] = 0;
A[1] = 0;
A[2] = 0;
A[3] = 0;
System.out.println(solution(A));
 }
}
```

Comment: It does improve the performance to the 66% but still not satisfactory

Comment: are you sure? I got 100% for correctness and complexity

Answer (score 6):

Got 100% with simple BFS:

```
public class Jump {
    int pos;
    int move;
    public Jump(int pos, int move) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.move = move;
    }
}

public int solution(int[] A) {

    int n = A.length;
    List < Integer > fibs = fibArray(n + 1);
    Queue < Jump > positions = new LinkedList < Jump > ();
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[n + 1];

    if (A.length <= 2)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < fibs.size(); i++) {
        int initPos = fibs.get(i) - 1;
        if (A[initPos] == 0)
            continue;
        positions.add(new Jump(initPos, 1));
        visited[initPos] = true;
    }

    while (!positions.isEmpty()) {
        Jump jump = positions.remove();
        for (int j = fibs.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            int nextPos = jump.pos + fibs.get(j);
            if (nextPos == n)
                return jump.move + 1;
            else if (nextPos < n && A[nextPos] == 1 && !visited[nextPos]) {
                positions.add(new Jump(nextPos, jump.move + 1));
                visited[nextPos] = true;
            }
        }
    }


    return -1;
}


private List < Integer > fibArray(int n) {
    List < Integer > fibs = new ArrayList < > ();
    fibs.add(1);
    fibs.add(2);
    while (fibs.get(fibs.size() - 1) + fibs.get(fibs.size() - 2) <= n) {
        fibs.add(fibs.get(fibs.size() - 1) + fibs.get(fibs.size() - 2));
    }
    return fibs;
}
```

Comment: I just found out that using a visited array is unnecessary. you could use minimum count of jumps instead to find the optimum solution.
check here: https://www.martinkysel.com/codility-fibfrog-solution/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript 100%

```
function solution(A) {
    function fibonacciUntilNumber(n) {
        const fib = [0,1];
        while (true) {
            let newFib = fib[fib.length - 1] + fib[fib.length - 2];
            if (newFib > n) {
                break;
            }
            fib.push(newFib);
        }
        return fib.slice(2);
    }
    A.push(1);
    const fibSet = fibonacciUntilNumber(A.length);
    if (fibSet.includes(A.length)) return 1;
    const reachable = Array.from({length: A.length}, () => -1);

    fibSet.forEach(jump => {
        if (A[jump - 1] === 1) {
            reachable[jump - 1] = 1;
        }
    })

    for (let index = 0; index < A.length; index++) {
        if (A[index] === 0 || reachable[index] > 0) {
            continue;
        }
        let minValue = 100005;
        for (let jump of fibSet) {
            let previousIndex = index - jump;
            if (previousIndex < 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (reachable[previousIndex] > 0 && minValue > reachable[previousIndex]) {
                minValue = reachable[previousIndex];
            }
        }
        if (minValue !== 100005) {
            reachable[index] = minValue + 1;
        }
    }
    return reachable[A.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got 100%- solution in C.

```
typedef struct state {
    int pos;
    int step;
}state;
int solution(int A[], int N) {

    int f1 = 0;
    int f2 = 1;
    int count = 2;
    // precalculating count of maximum possible fibonacci numbers to allocate array in next loop. since this is C language we do not have flexible dynamic structure as in C++
    while(1)
    {
        int f3 =  f2 + f1;
        if(f3 > N)
            break;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
        ++count;
    }
    int fib[count+1];
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    int i = 2;
    // calculating fibonacci numbers in array
    while(1)
    {
        fib[i] =  fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
        if(fib[i] > N)
            break;
        ++i;
    }
    // reversing the fibonacci numbers because we need to create minumum jump counts with bigger jumps
    for(int j = 0, k = count; j < count/2; j++,k--)
    {
        int t = fib[j];
        fib[j] = fib[k];
        fib[k] = t;
    }
    state q[N];
    int front = 0 ;
    int rear = 0;
    q[0].pos = -1;
    q[0].step = 0;
    int que_s = 1;
    while(que_s > 0)
    {
        state s =  q[front];
        front++;
        que_s--;
        for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            int nextpo = s.pos + fib[i];
            if(nextpo == N)
            {
                return s.step+1;
            }
            else if(nextpo > N || nextpo < 0 || A[nextpo] == 0){
           
                continue;  
            }
            else
            {
                q[++rear].pos = nextpo;
                q[rear].step = s.step + 1;
                que_s++;
                A[nextpo] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I will write it in Java and test later on. If the performance seems better, will update you.

Answer (score 1):

Python 100% answer.

For me the easiest solution was to locate all leaves within one fib jump of -1.  Then consider each of these leaves to be index[0] and find all jumps from there.
Each generation or jump is recorded in a set until a generation contains len(A) or no more jumps can be found.

```
def gen_fib(n):
    fn = [0,1]
    i = 2
    s = 2
    while s < n:
        s = fn[i-2] + fn[i-1]
        fn.append(s)
        i+=1
    return fn

def new_paths(A, n, last_pos, fn):
    """
    Given an array A of len n.
    From index last_pos which numbers in fn jump to a leaf?
    returns list: set of indexes with leaves.
    """
    paths = []
    for f in fn:
        new_pos = last_pos + f
        if new_pos == n or (new_pos < n and A[new_pos]):
            paths.append(new_pos)
    return path

def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    if n < 3:
        return 1

    # A.append(1) # mark final jump
    fn = sorted(gen_fib(100000)[2:]) # Fib numbers with 0, 1, 1, 2..  clipped to just 1, 2..
    # print(fn)
    paths = set([-1]) # locate all the leaves that are one fib jump from the start position.

    jump = 1
    while True:
        # Considering each of the previous jump positions - How many leaves from there are one fib jump away
        paths =  set([idx for pos in paths for idx in new_paths(A, n, pos, fn)])

        # no new jumps means game over!
        if not paths:
            break

        # If there was a result in the new jumps record that
        if n in paths:
            return jump
            
        jump += 1

    return -1
```

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training4GQV8Y-9ES/

https://github.com/niall-oc/things/blob/master/codility/fib_frog.py

Answer (score 1):

//100% on codility Dynamic Programming Solution. https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training7WSQJW-WTX/

```
class Solution {
  public int solution(int[] A) {
    int n = A.length + 1;
    int dp[] = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        dp[i] = -1;
    }
    int f[] = new int[100005];
    f[0] = 1;
    f[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2;i<100005;i++) {
        f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];
    }
    for(int i=-1;i<n;i++) {
        if(i == -1 || dp[i] > 0) {
            for(int j=0;i+f[j] <n;j++) {
                if(i + f[j] == n -1  || A[i+f[j]] == 1) {
                    if(i == -1) {
                        dp[i + f[j]] = 1;
                    } else if(dp[i + f[j]] == -1) {
                        dp[i + f[j]] = dp[i] + 1;
                    } else {
                        dp[i + f[j]] = Math.min(dp[i + f[j]], dp[i] + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
    }

    return dp[n - 1];
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 100% solution

```
def solution(a)
  f = 2.step.inject([1,2]) {|acc,e| acc[e] = acc[e-1] + acc[e-2]; break(acc) if acc[e] > a.size + 1;acc }.reverse
  mins = []

  (a.size + 1).times do |i|
    next mins[i] = -1 if i < a.size && a[i] == 0

    mins[i] = f.inject(nil) do |min, j|
        k = i - j
        next min if k < -1
        break 1 if k == -1
        next min if mins[k] < 0
        [mins[k] + 1, min || Float::INFINITY].min
    end || -1
  end

  mins[a.size]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have translated the previous `C` solution to Java and find the performance is improved.

[image]

```
import java.util.*;


class Solution {

        private static class State {

        int pos;
        int step;

        public State(int pos, int step) {

            this.pos = pos;
            this.step = step;
        }
    }


    public static int solution(int A[]) {

        int N = A.length;

        int f1 = 0;
        int f2 = 1;

        int count = 2;

        while (true) {

            int f3 = f2 + f1;

            if (f3 > N) {
                break;
            }

            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;

            ++count;
        }


        int[] fib = new int[count + 1];

        fib[0] = 0;
        fib[1] = 1;

        int i = 2;

        while (true) {

            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

            if (fib[i] > N) {
                break;
            }

            ++i;
        }

        for (int j = 0, k = count; j < count / 2; j++, k--) {

            int t = fib[j];

            fib[j] = fib[k];
            fib[k] = t;
        }

        State[] q = new State[N];

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {

            q[j] = new State(-1,0);
        }

        int front = 0;
        int rear = 0;

        // q[0].pos = -1;
        // q[0].step = 0;

        int que_s = 1;

        while (que_s > 0) {

            State s = q[front];

            front++;
            que_s--;

            for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

                int nextpo = s.pos + fib[i];

                if (nextpo == N) {
                    return s.step + 1;
                }

                //
                else if (nextpo > N || nextpo < 0 || A[nextpo] == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                //
                else {

                    q[++rear].pos = nextpo;
                    q[rear].step = s.step + 1;

                    que_s++;

                    A[nextpo] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript with 100%.
Inspired from [here](https://www.martinkysel.com/codility-fibfrog-solution/).

```
function solution(A) {
  const createFibs = n => {
    const fibs = Array(n + 2).fill(null)
    fibs[1] = 1
    for (let i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
      fibs[i] = fibs[i - 1] + fibs[i - 2]
    }
    return fibs
  }
  const createJumps = (A, fibs) => {
    const jumps = Array(A.length + 1).fill(null)
    let prev = null
    for (i = 2; i < fibs.length; i++) {
      const j = -1 + fibs[i]
      if (j > A.length) break
      if (j === A.length || A[j] === 1) {
        jumps[j] = 1
        if (prev === null) prev = j
      }
    }
    if (prev === null) {
      jumps[A.length] = -1
      return jumps
    }
    while (prev < A.length) {
      for (let i = 2; i < fibs.length; i++) {
        const j = prev + fibs[i]
        if (j > A.length) break
        if (j === A.length || A[j] === 1) {
          const x = jumps[prev] + 1
          const y = jumps[j]
          jumps[j] = y === null ? x : Math.min(y, x)
        }
      }
      prev++
      while (prev < A.length) {
        if (jumps[prev] !== null) break
        prev++
      }
    }
    if (jumps[A.length] === null) jumps[A.length] = -1
    return jumps
  }
  const fibs = createFibs(26)
  const jumps = createJumps(A, fibs)
  return jumps[A.length]
}

const A = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
console.log(A)
const s = solution(A)
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a QUEUE AND NOT A STACK. This is a form of breadth-first search and your code needs to visit nodes that were added first to the queue to get the minimum distance.
A stack uses the last-in, first-out mechanism to remove items while a queue uses the first-in, first-out mechanism.
I copied and pasted your exact code but used a queue instead of a stack and I got 100% on codility.

Comment: It's always better if you can implement the scenario with a sample code and post your answer with something useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

[100% C++ solution](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingKAD5GF-R52/)

More answers in [my github](https://github.com/Behrouz-m/Codility)

Inspired from [here](https://www.martinkysel.com/codility-fibfrog-solution/)

**Solution1 : Bottom-Top**, using Dynamic programming algorithm (storing calculated values in an array)

```cpp
vector<int> getFibonacciArrayMax(int MaxNum) {
    if (MaxNum == 0)
        return vector<int>(1, 0);
    vector<int> fib(2, 0);
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; fib[fib.size()-1] + fib[fib.size() - 2] <= MaxNum; i++)
        fib.push_back(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
    return fib;
}

int solution(vector<int>& A) {
    int N = A.size();
    A.push_back(1);
    N++;
    vector<int> f = getFibonacciArrayMax(N);
    const int oo = 1'000'000;
    vector<int> moves(N, oo);
    
    for (auto i : f)
        if (i - 1 >= 0 && A[i-1])
            moves[i-1] = 1;
    
    for (int pos = 0; pos < N; pos++) {
        if (A[pos] == 0)
            continue;

        for (int i = f.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (pos + f[i] < N && A[pos + f[i]]) {
                moves[pos + f[i]] = min(moves[pos]+1, moves[pos + f[i]]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (moves[N - 1] != oo) {
        return moves[N - 1];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Solution2: Top-Bottom** using `set` container:

```cpp
#include <set>

int solution2(vector<int>& A) {
    int N = A.size();

    vector<int> fib = getFibonacciArrayMax(N);

    set<int> positions;
    positions.insert(N);
    for (int jumps = 1; ; jumps++)
    {
        set<int> new_positions;
        for (int pos : positions)
        {
            for (int f : fib)
            {
                // return jumps if we reach to the start point
                if (pos - (f - 1) == 0)
                    return jumps;
                
                int prev_pos = pos - f;
                
                // we do not need to calculate bigger jumps.
                if (prev_pos < 0)
                    break;
                
                if (prev_pos < A.size() && A[prev_pos])
                    new_positions.insert(prev_pos);
            }
        }
        if (new_positions.size() == 0)
            return -1;
        positions = new_positions;
    }

    return -1;
}
```