# FibFrog Codility Problem - Optimising for Performance

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, fibonacci

I'm trying to solve the [FibFrog](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training72NHZJ-ME5/) Codility problem and I came up with the following approach:

1. If `len(A)` is 0 we know we can reach the other side in one jump.
2. If `len(A) + 1` is a fibonacci number, we can also reach it in one jump.
3. Else, we loop through A, and for the positions we can reach, we check if we can either reach them directly from -1 using a fibonacci number `(idx + 1 in fibonaccis)` or if we can reach them by first jumping to another position (`reachables`) and then jumping to the current position. In either case, we also check if we can go from the current position to the end of the river - if we can, then we can return because we found the minimum number of steps required.
4. Finally, if `unreachable` is `True` once this loop completes, this means we can't reach any position using a Fibonacci number, so we return -1.

I'm [getting](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training72NHZJ-ME5/) 83% correctness and 0% performance with this approach.

I understand the solution is `O(n^2)`, assuming the array consists of only `1`, the nested loop `for v in reachables:` would run `n` times - however I'm not sure how else I can compute this, since for each of the positions I need to check whether we can reach it from the start of the array, or from any previous positions using a fibonacci number.

```
    def solution(A):
        if len(A) == 0: return 1 
        fibonaccis = fibonacci(len(A) + 3)
        if len(A) + 1 in fibonaccis: return 1
        leaves = [0] * len(A)
        unreachable = True
        reachables = []
        for idx, val in enumerate(A): 
            if val == 1: 
                if idx + 1 in fibonaccis: 
                    unreachable = False
                    leaves[idx] = 1
                    if len(A) - idx in fibonaccis: 
                        return 2
                    reachables.append(idx)
                elif len(reachables) > 0: 
                    for v in reachables: 
                        if idx - v in fibonaccis: 
                            leaves[idx] = leaves[v] + 1
                            if len(A) - idx in fibonaccis: 
                                return leaves[v] + 2
                            reachables.append(idx)
                            break
        if unreachable: return -1 
        if len(A) - reachables[-1] in fibonaccis: 
            return leaves[reachables[-1]] + 1
    
    def fibonacci(N): 
        arr = [0] * N
        arr[1] = 1
        for i in range(2, N): 
            arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]
        return arr
```

Comment: Maybe it's a duplicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625022/

Comment: It definitely isn't duplicated because the question you linked is in Java and it's a completely different implementation as well - I'm asking what specifically is wrong with my solution, not how I can solve this differently in Java.

Comment: It does not work - as I mentioned in the question it has 83% correctness.

Comment: There are O(log N) Fibonacci numbers <= N.  If you limit your consideration to the numbers <= len(A)+1, then your algorithm would take O(N log N) time.  It doesn't look correct,  though, since I don't see you comparing path lengths anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions for improving performance of your algorithm -

- If `len(A) = 100000`, you are calculating 100003 fibonacci numbers, while we only need fibonacci numbers which are less than 100k, which would be <30 of them.
- Your solution is `O(n^4)`, since each `X in reachables` or `Y in fibonaccis` operation is `O(N)` where `N` is `len(A)`. (and length of `fibonaccis` being `N` because of above issue)
- Since you are doing a lot of `item in list` operations on `fibonaccis` and `reachables`, consider making it a `set` or a `dictionary` for faster(`O(1)` instead of `O(n)`) lookup.
- Even with the above changes, the algorithm would be `O(N^2)` because of nested looping across `A` and `reachables`, so you need to come up with a better approach.

With your existing implementation, you need to traverse through all the paths and then in the end you will get the smallest number of jumps.

Instead of this approach, if you start at `0`, and then keep a count of the number of jumps you have taken so far, and maintain how far(and to which numbers) you can reach after each jump then you can easily find the minimum jumps required to reach the end. (this will also save on redundant work you would have to do in case you have all `1`s in A.

e.g. for

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
fibonacci = set(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

At first jump, we can reach following 1-based indexes -

```
reachable = [1, 2, 3, 5]
jumps = 1
```

After second jump

```
reachables = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
jumps = 2
```

After third jump

```
reachables = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
jumps = 3
```

so you have reached the end(`10`) after 3 jumps.

Please check out @nialloc's answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64558623/8677071 which seems to be doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check out also my solution, which scores 100% on Codility tests and is easy to comprehend.

The idea is to track all possible positions of the frog after k jumps. If possible position == n, return k.

```
def fib_up_to(n):
    numbers = [1]
    i = 1
    while True:
        new_num = (numbers[-2] + numbers[-1]) if i > 1 else 2
        if new_num > n:
            break
        numbers.append(new_num)
        i += 1
    return numbers

def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    numbers = fib_up_to(n+1)

    possible_positions = set([-1])
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        positions_after_k = set()
        for pos in possible_positions:
            for jump in numbers:
                if pos + jump == n:
                    return k
                if pos + jump < n and A[pos + jump]:
                    positions_after_k.add(pos + jump)
        possible_positions = positions_after_k
    return -1
```